# Merge map of maps(nested maps) by retaining all values of same keys es6

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to merge 2 maps which have keys and values(are maps again).

_.merge works fine for 2 regular maps but not working for map of maps or nested maps.

```
map1 = {k1: {c1: v1, c2: v2}, k2: {c1: v1, c2: v2}};
map2 = {k1: {c3: v3, c4: v4}, k2: {c3: v3, c4: v4}};
```

Expecting

```
mergedMap = {k1: {c1: v1, c2: v2, c3: v3, c4: v4}, k2: {c1: v1, c2: v2, c3: v3, c4: v4}};
```

Comment: underscore doesn't have an `_.merge` method. Do you mean lodash?

Comment: Sorry, I meant lodash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#mergeWith) recursively.

ES6 solution:

```js
const recursiveMerge = (...args) =>
  _.mergeWith({}, ...args, (objValue, srcValue) => {
    if(typeof srcValue === 'object') {
      return recursiveMerge(objValue, srcValue);
    }
  });

const map1 = {k1: {c1: 'v1', c2: 'v2'}, k2: {c1: 'v1', c2: 'v2'}};
const map2 = {k1: {c3: 'v3', c4: 'v4'}, k2: {c3: 'v3', c4: 'v4'}};

const result = recursiveMerge(map1, map2);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

ES5 solution:

```js
function recursiveMerge() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
  var params = [{}].concat(args).concat([
    function(objValue, rcValue) {
      if (typeof srcValue === 'object') {
        return recursiveMerge(objValue, srcValue);
      }
    }]);

  return _.mergeWith.apply(_, params);
}

var map1 = {k1: {c1: 'v1', c2: 'v2'}, k2: {c1: 'v1', c2: 'v2'}};
var map2 = {k1: {c3: 'v3', c4: 'v4'}, k2: {c3: 'v3', c4: 'v4'}};

var result = recursiveMerge(map1, map2);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ori. I tried using this and I am getting "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ..." , may be my setup is not accepting the ...args

Comment: Ignore the previous (deleted) comment. You wrote ES6, and the '...' are ES6 destructuring, which are not supported on every browser. I've added a non ES6 solution.

Comment: I just tried this but I am still getting an empty map returned :(

Comment: Life is annoying sometimes :) As you can see both examples work in the browser, using lodash. Try to find the difference between your implementation and mine.

Comment: Actually my intention was to merge 2 maps not object maps. I gave the object maps in map1 and map2, but I was actually using maps. I changed all my maps to object maps and _.merge worked just fine. Thanks for your help